# depth_image_proc for TYPE_8UC1 stereo images

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I found this cool package to process a disparity map, I got from a stereo camera pair, and compute a point_cloud:
https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/tree/indigo/depth_image_proc

Here is my problem: The stereo pair has its own FPGA and readily outputs a disparity map of type sensor_msgs::Image with image encoding MONO8. I would like to use the above package, in particular this nodelet
https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/indigo/depth_image_proc/src/nodelets/point_cloud_xyz.cpp ,
to compute a sensor_msgs:PoitCloud2 message from that. However the package only provides templates for image encodings:  TYPE_16UC1 or TYPE_32FC1 (as mentioned in Line 117 and 121 of the nodelet).

I found a way to convert from MONO8 to TYPE_16UC1 so I can use the above nodelet, however I do not think this is a very elegant or efficient solution. I would rather add the possibility to process TYPE_8UC1 images with the nodelet (Conversion from MONO8 to 8UC1 should be less expensive, right?). I think I have to add a template for "uint8_t" in this file
https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/indigo/depth_image_proc/include/depth_image_proc/depth_traits.h

Unfortunately, I have a very poor understanding of image encodings etc. and I am not sure what exactly I would need to add. Could somebody give me a hint on how to do that, or point me to some recourses, where I could find out?
Or do you have better suggestions to solve my problem?

I am using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04

Really appreciate your answers :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285948/depth_image_proc-for-type_8uc1-stereo-images/) by [Jerzy97](https://answers.ros.org/users/34231/jerzy97/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To my understanding, I think there is a confusion in your stereo camera's driver. Mono8 is a color encoding, which contains one 8-bit **monochromatic channel**.  TYPE_16UC1 in [depth_image_proc](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/indigo/depth_image_proc/src/nodelets/point_cloud_xyz.cpp) is a type of unsigned 16-bit **depth channel**. So basically, these are 2 different things.

IMO, your proposal to convert from Mono8 to TYPE_8UC1/TYPE_16UC1 doesn't really make sense. My suggestion is that you change your camera's driver to output correct encoding.

AFAIK, TYPE_16UC1 in [depth_image_proc](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/indigo/depth_image_proc/src/nodelets/point_cloud_xyz.cpp) gives you values in millimeter unit, while TYPE_32UC1 returns meter unit.

---

Originally posted by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) with karma: 358 on 2018-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jerzy97](https://answers.ros.org/users/34231/jerzy97/) on 2018-03-20**:
Thanks a lot!
I was able to change that and now I am getting the point cloud.